# Using raster for r.sim.sediment?

Tags: qgis, data

I'm quite new to QGIS.

What data will I need to use the `r.sim.sediment` processing tool?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r.sim.sediment` is a tool from the GRASS toolbox. You can find documentation for GRASS tools by clicking the "Help" link in the QGIS tool dialog for that tool, or go straight here:

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.sim.sediment.html

It shows that you need a few raster data sets over your study area, including elevation, water depth and so on.

If that documentation is insufficient then chase the references given and/or search for a tutorial or example that uses it - this might be a tutorial based on GRASS rather than a QGIS one but will use the same functions that you can get from the GRASS toolbox in QGIS.